# lazy-loaded states with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading

My lazy loading library is this: [`ocLazyLoad`](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) and I'm attempting to use it with `ui-router`.

I have my routes declared in two separate files that are concatenated together in the build process. Here is what the concatenated output is:

```
angular.module('asdf').config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/static/welcome.html'
        });
}]);

angular.module('asdf').config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('cohort-definition-editor', {
            url: '/cohort-definition-editor',
            templateUrl: 'components/cohort-definition-editor/mui/cohort-definition-editor.html',
            controller: 'CDEController',
            data: {
                pageTitle: "Cohort Definition Editor",
                subTitle: "Cohort Definition Editor",
                category: "Apps"
            },
            params: {
                _form_LinkId: undefined
            },
            resolve: {
                dep: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                    // console.log('test');
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                        'components/cohort-definition-editor/mui/cohort-definition-editor.min.js',
                        'components/cohort-definition-editor/mui/cohort-definition-editor.min.css'
                    ]);
                }]
            }
        });
}]);
```

(A lot of the second file is autogenerated, so the repetition is intentional.)

My problem is this: I cannot refresh the page when on a lazy-loaded state. I will start my pageload here: http://127.0.0.1:9001/#!/ and then click a link with a `ui-sref="cohort-definition-editor"` that loads this url: http://127.0.0.1:9001/#!/cohort-definition-editor (with the proper state/html fragment/etc). If I refresh the page, I am instead greeted an "empty" state. Normally, `views/static/welcome.html` would be displayed by default but I get nothing where I should have the `cohort-definition-editor` HTML fragment displayed, and the URL is still the correct one.

I've added a bunch of watchers to the ui-router events and none of them fire on pageload. I've also tried adding a console.log statement (see above, commented in the resolve section) and that also does not fire, leading me to believe something is wrong with the DI on pageload. It's not erroring out though, so it's difficult to trace.

Is there a better way to lazy-load ui-router states, or am I just doing it wrong? For reference, I first learned of `ocLazyLoad` from [here](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin3/angularjs/#/dashboard.html) which does a similar thing and it definitely works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As luck would have it, if you refresh the page but your state has a required param that isn't set to a default value (ie, I have a param set to `undefined`) then the route simply cannot be loaded as it requires a param. As a result the best thing to do here is to make the param have a default value.